# Mongodb aggregation in deep

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have scheme like this below. I'm using nodejs mongodb offical driver. 
Could I use aggregation pipeline framework for grouping someprop.subpop.title?

I can make it with map reduce but aggregation is much more faster than map/reduce. I couldn't find any example to go deep in objects when grouping.

```
{
    id_ : ObjectID("234bv123"),
    username : "ugurozpinar",
    someprop : {
        subprop : [
            {title:"Movies",count:5},
            {title:"Sport",count:10}
        ]    
    }
},
{
    id_ : ObjectID("234bv123"),
    username : "otheruser",
    someprop : {
        subprop : [
            {title:"Movies",count:9},
            {title:"Theatre",count:8}
        ]    
    }
}
```

expected result

```
[
 {id_:"Movies",total:14},
 {id_:"Theatre",total:8},
 {id_:"Sport",total:10}
]
```

Comment: Since you have two titles in parallel inside subprop, are you trying to group by the first "title" element? or the combination of the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use dot notation to reach inside of objects and use `$unwind` with `$group` to get total counts by `title`:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$someprop.subprop'},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$someprop.subprop.title', 
        count: {$sum: '$someprop.subprop.count'}
    }}
])
```